# How to pass dynamic amount in paypal buy now button

Tags: paypal

I have made a paypal buy now button , but is not taking dynamic amount which i am sending by form like
 amount variable in input type hidden

It only takes price which is set while creating form.

Please give me solution , so that i can pass dynamic price and get payment for it.

Comment: Than please provide solution

Comment: @dipanshu have a look at the link to the duplicate.

Comment: @Alex , the solutions which are provided are old now and did not work with latest paypal

Comment: Need to see what code you are trying.

Comment: <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20.00">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="mahajan.dipanshu@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="WBFY55PUM76RL">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

Answer (score 4):

Finally my this code works now

```
  <form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' name='form'>
  <input type='hidden' name='business' value='myname@gmail.com'>
  <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'> 
  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='itemname'>
  <input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='2'>
  <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='2 0'>
  <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
  <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
   <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://cancel.com'>
     <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://return.com/'>
   <input type="image"   src="https://paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

As of June 29, 2017 I see this not working.  Paypal has again changed its rules, and I don't think it any longer accepts hidden HTML fields in the form submission: they must be set in the button editor at Paypal.

Comment: Why is this not THE accepted answer? After reading myself in dizzying circles, I'm satisfied that I've read the definitive answer (for me). Now it's just a matter of structuring the correct input sequencing.

Comment: If that's the case, any evidence? And what would be the solution?

Comment: I don't have any evidence other than that I see this feature not working, and Paypal customer service confirmed to me that it has been deprecated.  Paypal's documentation is confusing because they don't remove pages for obsolete and deprecated features, so you must check carefully that what you're reading is current.
As far as I know there's no solution right now: as of July 2017 Paypal does not support transactions with a customer-specified amount originating from a Buy Now button.  
I too would have liked to see it work.

Comment: 2020-02-12: As of today, I was able to create a so-called non hosted button on PayPal, set the amount to pay in Javascript, and make a test payment using it. Here's a sample guide on how to create these: https://support.qualityunit.com/476567-How-to-create-PayPal-non-hosted-non-encrypted-buttons **So, the answer I'm commenting under is not correct.**